# Insert user into database via Entity Framework does not work

Tags: wpf, database, entity-framework

I created a service-based database (`.mdf` file) in Visual Studio 2013 and then I wanted to use Entity Framework model designed from database. Select methods work fine but when I'm trying to do some inserts - they do not work, I'm not even getting errors.

Code:

```
Database1Entities data = new Database1Entities();

user player = new user();
player.Nick = "halo halo";

data.user.Add(player);

data.SaveChanges();
```

and table definition

[image]

I will be grateful for any help, thanks.

Feel free to ask for more informations if needed

Comment: Activate the SQL logging to see what SQL statements are being sent to the database: `data.Database.Log = s => Console.WriteLine(s);` (if the console is not visible, write to something else, but the idea is the same)  If all the SQL looks good, then make sure you are pointing to the correct database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after saving the data, query the database:

```
using (Database1Entities dbe = new Database1Entities())
{
 var query = from usr in dbe.user select usr;
}
```

and check the contents of `query`.

if the data you just inserted is there, then your MDF file is getting over-written in your compile/execute cycle. In visual studio mark the MDF file as *"Do not copy"* in the properties window.